# Tests have shown that the quality of locally produced cars is somewhat higher than imported vehicles

Tags: comparatives, parallelism

I know that "higher than that of imported" would be better, but how wrong is it as it is?

> Tests have shown that the quality of locally produced cars is somewhat higher than imported vehicles.

Comment: The frequency of this error is somewhat higher than other errors.

Comment: If you know it can be better, why are you curious about the inferior?

Answer (score 1):

If the comparison is about quality, you're right. If the cars are being compared, it could be *performance* or *efficiency* but "better" will take the place of "higher".

In your example, it should be: "... higher than that of **the** imported vehicles".

If we consider: "The temperature here is higher than in the cottage-country." - the presence of "in" makes the difference.